# OneLogin Create Session Login Token API returns status 400 with message: Bad Request

Tags: c#, api, onelogin

I am developing a C# application which needs to use the onelogin API to retrieve a session token. I am able to authenticate and and create a token with the following code:

```
WebRequest Authrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/token");

Authrequest.Method = "POST";
Authrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
Authrequest.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
Authrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: client_id:XXXXXXX7bbf2c50200d8175206f664dc28ffd3ec66eef0bfedb68c3366420dc, client_secret:XXXXXXXXXX6ba2802187feb23f6450c6812b8e6639361d24aa83f12010f ");


using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Authrequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string Authjson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {

        grant_type = "client_credentials"

    });

    streamWriter.Write(Authjson);
}
WebResponse AuthReponse;
AuthReponse = Authrequest.GetResponse();

Stream receiveStream = AuthReponse.GetResponseStream ();

// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream);


JObject incdata = JObject.Parse(readStream.ReadToEnd());
string sToken = incdata["data"][0]["access_token"].Value<string>();

AuthReponse.Close();
```

However, when running the Create Session Login Token with the following code, it only returns a 400 error, and the message has no detail. Just Bad Request:

```
//Get the session token for the specified user, using the token recieved from previous web request

WebRequest request =     WebRequest.Create("https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/login/auth");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("authorization", "bearer:" + sToken);


using (var streamWriter2 = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {

        username_or_email = sUsername,
        password = sPassword,
        subdomain = "comp-alt-dev"


    });

    streamWriter2.Write(json);
}


WebResponse response;            
response = request.GetResponse();


string streamText = "";
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (responseStream)
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    using (streamReader)
    {
        streamText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        streamReader.Close();
        //
    }
    responseStream.Close();
}
```

Any ideas?

-Thank you

Comment: How is your service defined at the endpoint: `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/login/auth`? Can you run this code locally and attach your debugger to it? Or is this a service outside of your control?

Comment: It is out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

Also for anyone who may be getting this error. in C# the email is case sensitive. I tried User.email.com. In onelogin it was saved as user@email.com. changing the c# to lower case fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what goes over the wire to the OneLogin endpoint...

OK Thanks.  So it appears your subdomain does not exist.  If you give me an email in the account I can find the correct subdomain value for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us know what payload you're sending across the wire to the .../1/login/auth endpoint as well as the response (either as others have suggested as packet snoop, or just as a debug output from the code)

400 means either bad json or the endpoint requires MFA, so this will narrow it down.

~thanks!

Comment: Here is the payload    {"username_or_email":"useri@computing-alt.com","password":"Temp!23","subdomain":"comp-alt-dev"}   And the response is :  {"status":{"error":true,"code":400,"type":"bad request","message":"bad request"}}

Comment: I've confirmed that a bad username or email will cause the 400 error.

If useri@computing-alt.com isn't a valid email on your account, you'll get a 400 not a 401

Comment: Btw - I just confirmed your subdomain does exist. I was able to generate a 401 when I passed in a valid user and a 400 when I passed in an invalid user.

I'm pretty sure the user string you're passing in is non-existent / malformed

Comment: Thank you very much. I deleted my test user then re-added it and it is working fine now. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just joining the troubleshooting effort =) -- I can replicate a 400 Bad Request status code with a "bad request" message when the request body contains a `username_or_email` and/or `subdomain` value that does not exist, or if the request body is empty.

Comment: Perhaps my subdomain is incorrect. I looked it up on onelogin so I am not sure.